# Trouble installing javafx and dl4j together with gradle

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, javafx, dl4j

So I'm trying to use javafx and dl4j in my application for which I use gradle to manage my dependencies.
For javafx I just add it as a gradle plugin and require the modules in my module-info.java, dl4j is just added as a regular dependency. The problem is that appearently dl4j doesnt like it when there is a module-info file present because it just gives me a bunch InvalidModuleDescriptorException because dl4j is missing packages (even though everything shows up in the external libraries tab!). So appearently dl4j doesnt handle modules very? As far as I know I do need the module-info though because otherwise javafx will give me the old "Runtime components are missing"... Maybe someone knows whats going on?

Comment: Would you mind filing an issue over at https://github.com/eclipse/deeplearning4j/issues? Maybe there's something missing. It would be good to have more information.